# HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath rejects <link> inside body tag

Tags: html, perl, xpath

I'm using `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` to parse a complex HTML doc and then edit it, before writing it back to disk. The problem I'm running into is that it rejects `<link...>` tags inside the `<body>` block when I try to parse HTML content (`$tree->parse_content($page);`):

> HTML::Parse: Header element `<link>` in body

I know these were illegal until HTML5, it seems that they are legal now.  Does anyone know of a way to either get the tell treebuilder that this is legal, or just make it accept it, even if it throws a warning.  These are not making it to the output stage, and messing up the layout.

Answer (score 2):

The `<link>` element is invalid within the `<body>` for HTML 4 and its XHTML 1 variant. It is permitted within the `body` by the HTML 5 draft if it has an `itemprop` attribute, but HTML 5 has yet to be ratified as a standard.

First you should make sure you have the latest version of [`HTML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser), which [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) uses to parse the HTML and is probably what is raising the error.

Then, you can try getting it to ignore the `<link>` elements, like this

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$tree->ignore_elements('link');
$tree->parse('myfile.html');
```

Comment: $tree->ignore_elements('link');   

That was what I would have been looking for, but it seems not to work.  When it's passed to $tree the parser seems to stop parsing at the first <link> tag, so the output is a partial header and an an empty body. 

On the HTML::Parser front, I've updated it the the current in CPAN with no change

Comment: as a further followup, ignore_tag gets rid of the errors at the cost of link tags never getting regenerated.  What I really want is "ignore_error_on_tag("link")"

Comment: @amacks: Are you able to let me have some data to test with? Somewhere like [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) perhaps?